# Defining iteration when encrypting data using aes 256 with pbkdf2 encryption

Tags: javascript, encryption, aes, cryptojs

Hi i was creating a password manager application with firebase and vanilla javascript and was using aes 256 bit with pbkdf2 encryption with a sha512 locally stored key.

this is the code i used -

```js
var keySize = 384;
var ivSize = 256;
var iterations = 1001;

function encrypt(msg, pass) {
    var salt = CryptoJS.lib.WordArray.random(128 / 8);

    var key = CryptoJS.PBKDF2(pass, salt, {
        keySize: keySize / 32,
        iterations: iterations
    });

    var iv = CryptoJS.lib.WordArray.random(128 / 8);

    var encrypted = CryptoJS.AES.encrypt(msg, key, {
        iv: iv,
        padding: CryptoJS.pad.Pkcs7,
        mode: CryptoJS.mode.CBC

    });

    // salt, iv will be hex 32 in length
    // append them to the ciphertext for use  in decryption
    var transitmessage = salt.toString() + iv.toString() + encrypted.toString();
    var encodeB4 = CryptoJS.enc.Base64.stringify(transitmessage);
    return encodeB4;
}

function decrypt(transitmessage, pass) {
    var decoded =
        const decoded = CryptoJS.enc.Utf8.stringify(transitmessage);

    var salt = CryptoJS.enc.Hex.parse(decoded.substr(0, 32));
    var iv = CryptoJS.enc.Hex.parse(decoded.substr(32, 32))
    var encrypted = decoded.substring(64);

    var key = CryptoJS.PBKDF2(pass, salt, {
        keySize: keySize / 32,
        iterations: iterations
    });

    var decrypted = CryptoJS.AES.decrypt(encrypted, key, {
        iv: iv,
        padding: CryptoJS.pad.Pkcs7,
        mode: CryptoJS.mode.CBC

    })
    return decrypted;
}
```

However now when i decrypt the encrypted data the site hangs,and if there are around 10-20 passwords the site becomes unresponsive,later i discover that the iterations were a problem due to that it takes so much time to encrypt and decrypt data,but when i looked up to other services like this eg.bitwarden they use around 100k iterations on the other hand i used only 1k in client side encryption/decryption process so how are they so fast and efficient.Is it possible to that the same using cryptoJS or any other library that can be used in vanilla javascript and if it is can anyone share code snippets,codepen or anything.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why do you derive the encryption key on the server and not on the client (and then send the encryption key via https to the server) ?

Comment: I remember that Crypto.js' PBKDF2 implementation was exponential instead of linear with the number of iterations a couple of years ago. I've tried to debug it, but didn't find the cause of this if this wasn't fixed by the current maintainer. You might need to use a different client-side implementation of PBKDF2.

Comment: @MichaelFehr the key is derived from the client side only that is a sha512 hash stored in  the localstorage of the browser and when the data is retrieved it decrypted by the sha512 hash stored in local storage

Comment: is there any other better library which does this work more efficiently so that we could add more iterations around 20k-30k maybe web crypto api or something else can anyone suggest with examples of snippets.